# How to use function in Class in PHP file

Tags: php, function, class, xampp

I'm developing a website for my project.
My folder structure looks like this:

```
/testingSite
    /src
        /WordBreaker.php
    /index.php
```

I have a problem when using a function in WordBreaker.php

Here is how the function is defined in WordBreaker.php

```
<?php
class WordBreaker
    {
        function breakIntoWords($text) 
        {
            $ranges = $this->breakIntoRanges($text);
            $textList = $this->rangesToTextList($text, $ranges);
            return $textList;
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is where I want to use a function (in index.php)

```
<?php
    include "src/WordBreaker.php";

    $instance = new WordBreaker ();

    if ( isset( $_POST['btnSubmit'] ) ) {
        $result = $instance->breakIntoWords($input);
    }
?>
```

When I test the site, the error occur

> Fatal error: Class 'WordBreaker' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\testingSite\index.php on line 4

What should I do?

Comment: It's a side note, but since you require the WordBreaker class available, change that `include` to `require` and I suspect you will get a not found error, or at least an error we can go from.

Comment: It doesn't work. I get the same error message.

Comment: That seems unlikely given the code and information you've provided. Maybe try providing the entirety of the WordBreaker class.

Comment: Here is the code of WordBreaker.php
http://paste.ofcode.org/FD8W4uxTsiPEtjWTJ6ykJ8

Comment: Try using `new PhlongTaIam\WordBreaker()`. The class is defined in a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Use `require_once` instead of `include`

```
<?php
    require_once("src/WordBreaker.php");

    $instance = new WordBreaker ();

    if ( isset( $_POST['btnSubmit'] ) ) {
        $result = $instance->breakIntoWords($input);
    }
?>
```

or you can add an autoloader function

```
<?php 
   function __autoload($class_name) {
      require_once $class_name . '.php';
   }

   $vars = new IUarts(); 
   print($vars->data);    
?>
```

Comment: That won't fix it, that will just cause a different error if the file isn't found.

Comment: Can you explain that? I think it's still make sense, because If the file doesn't exists then you will know there is something error.

Comment: Yes, you'll know there's an error. But that doesn't solve the problem, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can include it using **DIR**

```
require __DIR__."/src/WordBreaker.php";

$instance = new WordBreaker();
```

_ *DIR* _ is 'magical' and returns the directory of the current file without the trailing slash.

" If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(_ *FILE* _). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory."